# Constructor has object of abstract class as parameter

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, abstract

I have an interface called `IGrocery` with one method `public String getName()`.
Then there is one abstract class called `AbstractFood` which implements the interface and which has a variable `protected String name`.
Further there is one public class `Ingredient` (with one `private double amount`) which **must** have a constructor like this:

```
public Ingredient(AbstractFood food, double amount){
    this.amount=amount;
    ???
}
```

I don't understand how I can create an `Ingredient` object, as I would have to create an `AbstractFood` object before that (but the `AbstractFood` class is abstract).

Comment: Create an instance of a concrete sub-class of AbstractFood.

Comment: You can't instantiate an abstract class - these are only there to be extended (used) in your own class

Comment: ok thanks alot.
If the amount in the Ingredient constructor must be greater than zero, can I add into the constructor the following?
...
if (amount <= 0) {
throw new IllegalArgumentException(
"Amount must be positive");
}

Answer (score 3):

You have a class that inhertices from AbstractFood say:

```
public class Peanut extends AbstractFood
{
   public Peanut(){
     //code
   }
}
```

That way, you could give an instance of "Peanut" as parameter to the constructor :)

Answer (score 0):

- Create a subclass extending the abstract class
- If you don't want first approach: then use anonymous class approach:

  ```
  AbstractFood aFood = new AbstractFood() 
                               {
                                   // your implementation
                               };
  new Ingredient(aFood, someDoubleVal);
  ```